Clarification on Databricks DLT resources
When setting up DLT pipeline, there are 3 types of product edition, Core, Pro and Advanced. When I compare DLT Classic Core and DLT Classic Pro, the difference is that DLT Classic Pro can handle CDC. Does it means if I'm using DLT Classic Core, I have to enable change data feed, get data feed and do merging for my daily ingestion pipeline manually while DLT Classic Pro are not required to do all these steps?
I tried to use DLT Classic Core, seems like the DLT pipeline still able to capture the changes in bronze layer and reflect the changes in silver layer, so I'm a bit confuse on this change data capture (or it is only for streaming pipeline). Appreciate any clarification, thank you.
